# ASP.NET Core MediatR Dependency Injection - DbContext registration problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 6.0 application with CQRS pattern.

My problem is about dependency injection which occurs while following this process below

- P1 - Event handler registered as Transient
- P2 - IMediator injected to this event handler
- P3 - A command handler to be triggered by Mediator in event handler
- P4 - In this command handler, IOrderRepository is injected as Transient
- P5 - In OrderRepository DbContext is registered as default

---

First, I got an error like this;

[image: DbContext error]

---

- DB CONTEXT

  ```
  public class OrderDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
  {
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public OrderDbContext() : base()
    {

    }

    public OrderDbContext(DbContextOptions<OrderDbContext> options, IMediator mediator) : base(options)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }
  }
  ```
- ORDER COMMAND CQRS

  ```
  public class CreateOrderCommand : IRequest<bool>
  {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
  }
  ```
- P1 & P2

  ```
  public class BlaBlaIntegrationEventHandler
  {
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public BlaBlaEventHandler(IMediator mediator)
    {
       this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    public async Task Handle(BlaBlaEvent @event)
    {
        ......

        await mediator.Send(command);
    }
   }
  ```
- P3 & P4

  ```
  public class BlaBlaCommandHandler
  {
    private readonly IOrderRepository orderRepository;

    public BlaBlaCommandHandler(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
      this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
    }
  }
  ```
- P5

  ```
  public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
  {
    private readonly OrderDbContext dbContext;
    public OrderRepository(OrderDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public Order GetByIdAsync(intid)
    {
        ....
    } 
  }
  ```

All information needed,

- Mediator registration

  ```
  services.AddMediatR(m =>
  {
      m.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
  });
  ```
- Event handler registration

  ```
  services.AddTransient<BlaBlaEventHandler>();
  ```
- OrderRepository registration

  ```
  services.AddTransient<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
  ```
- DbContext registration

  ```
  services.AddDbContext<OrderDbContext>(opt =>
  {
      opt.UseSqlServer(configuration["OrderDbConnectionString"]);
      opt.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
  });
  ```

WHY DO I GET THIS ERROR ?

If I register Order Repository as scoped, then an error occurs for order repository...

What is the mistake I made about DI ????

Comment: Can you also include the `CreateOrderCommand` from the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DbContext is by default registering as scoped, and to resolve it requires that a scope be available, hence the error.

You might, depending on your specific needs:

1. Use the overload parameter for `AddDbContext` that accepts a `ServiceLifetime` value and register it as `ServiceLifetime.Transient`, thus making your DbContext transient
2. Create a scope in the class that requires the DbContext connection. Inject `IServiceScopeFactory` as a constructor parameter and set it to a private readonly variable, and you can create a scope and resolve your `DbContext`.

   ```
   public class YourClass 
   {
      private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

      public class YourClass(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, ...)
      {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        // ...
      }

      public async Task YourMethod()
      {
         // ...
         using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
         {
             var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetReqiredService<OrderDbContext>();
             // do work
         }
         // ...
      }
   }
   ```